# localhost Host with SSL [resolved]

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, localhost, wamp

I'm trying to set up my WAMP configuration in order to access (locally) to my website in SSL.
I'm running Wamp 3.1.4 64 bits on Windows10 with Apache 2.4.35 and php 7.2.10

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please edit your question to include the following information: What is the actual problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i was try this setup link follow.

https://zuziko.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-https-ssl-on-wamp-server/
all setp complite successfully even  G:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin  type command "httpd –t" and getting this: "Syntax is OK".
but still not working https://localhost